# Is there an analogue of the Gosper flowsnake on the Cartesian lattice?

Tags: fractals

The [Gosper curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper_curve) has a sort of dual [flowsnake](https://larryriddle.agnesscott.org/ifs/ksnow/flowsnake.htm) which is a space-filling curve on a hex lattice.  The unit motif traces a 7 hex 'super-hexagon' comprised of the origin and its six neighbors in the three +/- axis directions, which get connected into a super-super-hex of 49 hexes and so on.

I know there are plenty of [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) on a Cartesian (square) lattice like the Hilbert curve, z-order curve, Grey-coded curve etc.  But the flowsnake construction makes me wonder if there's an analogue whose basic unit links the origin with its four axis neighbors
$(x,y) = (0, 0), (\pm 1, 0), (0, \pm 1)$ into a `+` shape.
The recursive packing of these into a larger rotated version seems to work in a similar way (bad ascii art below), but I'm not sure how the path would trace.

Anyone run across a space filling curve that looks like this?

```
        . . 4 . . . .
        . 4 4 4 . 1 .
        . . 4 0 1 1 1 
        . 3 0 0 0 1 .
        3 3 3 0 2 . .
        . 3 . 2 2 2 .
        . . . . 2 . .
```

[image: Illustration of flowsnake construction connecting seven instances of the red 7 hexagon motif to create a self-similar 49 hex motif sketched in green, in turn connected to form a 777 hex motif, and so on]

Comment: rather than describing the proposed 5 square unit on the square lattice as a `+` sign, i guess calling it a rotated 'super-square' would be more apt to extend the analogy

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Ryde, author of the [planepath package](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::PlanePath) with many interesting 2D curves, pointed me at [Mandelbrot's quartet](http://www.fractalcurves.com/Root5.html).

Like the Gosper curve, we can construct a dual that fills the cartesian lattice based on a 5 unit 'super-cell' that recursively tiles the square grid.[image]